# how to get filesystem/usage with heapster in k8s cluster

Tags: go, kubernetes, heapster

How to get "filesystem/usage" with heapster in k8s cluster? I used heapster monitor k8s, but I can not get the node disk usage. Anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

curl -L 10.233.8.12:/api/v1/model/nodes/node1/metrics/filesystem/usage?labels="resource_id:/"
    `ws.Route(ws.GET("/nodes/{node-name}/metrics/{metric-name:*}").
        To(metrics.InstrumentRouteFunc("nodeMetrics", a.nodeMetrics)).
        Doc("Export a node-level metric").
        Operation("nodeMetrics").
        Param(ws.PathParameter("node-name", "The name of the node to lookup").DataType("string")).
        Param(ws.PathParameter("metric-name", "The name of the requested metric").DataType("string")).
        Param(ws.QueryParameter("start", "Start time for requested metric").DataType("string")).
        Param(ws.QueryParameter("end", "End time for requested metric").DataType("string")).
        Param(ws.QueryParameter("labels", "A comma-separated list of key:values pairs to use to search for a labeled metric").DataType("string")).
        Writes(types.MetricResult{}))`